# Set color from String array to Android View background

Tags: android, view, colors

I am having this two array; one is Int type and another is string type:

```
int[] COLOURS = { Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW,
        Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED };

String[] color = { "#ff0000","#ff0f00" ,"#ffff00"};
```

I am using this code to set color from the Integer array  to the background of a view according to value of progress:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    full_page.setBackgroundColor(COLOURS[progress]);

}
```

But I need to set color from the string array, from this one:

```
String[] color = { "#ff0000","#ff0f00" ,"#ffff00"};
```

but this is showing error in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like

```
full_page.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(COLOURS[progress]));
```

i hope its useful to you

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the string to Color like

```
   Color.parseColor("#ff0000");
```

In Your case for example:

```
   Color colOne = Color.parse(color[0]);
```